# Debug long running python script that crashes?

Tags: python, node.js

I have a complex python 2.7 script that is launched by a node.js app using spawn. This script runs fine most of the time, but occasionally, it crashes and I don't know why. I did not have this problem when launching the script from the command line or as a service.

To simulate this, I start the script via node.js, get the process id using the ps or pgrep command, then kill it using kill -9 on the process id. My question is how do my script to generate an error code or debug output when it crashes unexpectedly?

Comment: A process spawned with `spawn` in nodejs will return a child process that have `stdin` and `stderr` properties, which you can access to get the output log in the program console. You can read them and log them to a file or whatever. Maybe they show you the exact moment that the script fails. Also you can run the file manually with a python debugger and check what happens.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález my node app does attach to stdout and stderr, but I get nothing output when it crashes.